# initramfs mountpoint space Insufficient

Tags: linux

I try to boot from ethernet my own Linux FS :

- create an initramfs with a simple and very minimal fedora structure : ok
- boot with DHCP with a 2.6 kernel : ok
- kernel load the initramfs : ok
- a custom init.sh script is call : ok

So after the boot I have a Linux OS with an initramfs as filesystem.

With the initramfs, I have compiled some minimal applications.

The aim of this minimal boot is to make things without to have to mount
a hard disk or another filesystem.

My problem is that some applications, like mail, complain that disk
space is insuficient, and of course, df / result :

df /
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
-                            0         0         0   -  /

So, how to make the initramfs have a mountpoint with a real capacity
(capacity = RAM capacity ?)

Thanks for any help

Yves

Comment: Where do you want that storage to live ? In memory, an NFS server, a USB drive ? (Note that initramfs is a simple read-only, in memory, filesystem)

Comment: At this moment I mount an NFS storage, but I dont't want to "boot" on this, I would like to keep initramfs sufficient.
I have a RW structure with initramfs :
echo "test" > /tmp/test or echo "test" > /etc/test : write OK

Comment: THen presumably you can create /etc/fstab and add an entry for your nfs server, and run a script that runs mount -a , or just have said script mount the nfs server directly.

Comment: Consider there is no NFS or other filesystem anywhere. Just the initramfs but without positive capacity on df /. Maybe is not possible, but I would like the initramfs, that is in RW because it is loaded in RAM, become a valid mountpoint.

Comment: Then you're best off creating a tmpfs (which is a ram based filesystem) and mount it somewhere, you'll need to compile your kernel with tmpfs support - this is the common way for embedded systems which have no permanent storage to get a writable file system

Comment: I already tried to do it, but how to copy all the filesystem (so the initramfs already loaded) to the new mountpoint tmpfs ?